# SelectToken() with parenthesis in jToken throwing "Unexpected character while parsing path indexer" error

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I'm trying to deserialize and parse a JsonObj

```json
{ "obj": [
  {
    "name": "Kelly",
    "calculation": {
         "reff" : "apply(stringa/stringb)"
     },
    "value": "Number",
   }
  ]
}
```

```cs
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);
JObject parsedObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString );
var reffTokens = parsedObj.SelectTokens("$..reff");
foreach (JToken token in reffTokens.ToArray())
{
    var calculatedToken = parsedObj.SelectToken(token.ToString());   
}
```

I get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Unexpected character while parsing path indexer:
> Source=Newtonsoft.Json

If I remove the braces and have the calculation part as

```
"calculation": {
  "reff" : "stringa/stringb"
},
```

then it works fine. any suggestion on how to deserialize and parse JObject for parentheses? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? braces are reserved for grouping, [see here](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2). When you remove them, you just get a null as a result, so what do you mean by "it works fine"?

Comment: SelectToken() takes a JSONPath expression as input.  When you select for `stringa/stringb` you are selecting a property named `"stringa/stringb"` in the root object.  There is no such property, so nothing is returned.  When you select for `apply(stringa/stringb)` you get an error because `(` is a reserved character in JSONPath, used for grouping.  To search for a property with reserved characters you need to escape then as shown in the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm) like so: `['apply(stringa/stringb']`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/FpN78c.

Comment: But even if I fix your JSONPath expression to be `['apply(stringa/stringb']` then once again nothing is selected because there is are no properties named `"apply(stringa/stringb)"` or  `"stringa/stringb"` in the root object.  So can you explain what you are really trying to do here?  Are you really looking for a property with the `"reff"` value in the root object?

Comment: This is subset of the jsonObj here that i am trying to parse. I am looking for various properties in the root object, however when i have any with parantheses it is throwing this excpetion. Getting null as a result is what i'm expecting, instead of the exception that is being thrown. Also, I tried this as well: ['apply(stringa/stringb)'], however i was avoiding saving the json with [] braces, was trying to figure out if there was another solution here. Thanks for your responses, and would really appreciate or if you know of any other alternative!